# html5 <video> tag doesn't play mp4 files larger than 10 MB in chrome/firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I'm using the following code in my .aspx page

```
<video id="example_video_1"  controls preload="none" width="640" height="388" style="display:block; width: 796px; margin-left: 101px;"
                poster="<%= Url.Action("NewThumbnail", "Search", new { file = ViewData["Clipfile"], archiveDate = ViewData["ClipArchive"] , station =  ViewData["ClipStation"] }) %>"
                data-setup="{}">
      <source src="<%= Url.Action("Proxy", "Clip", new { file = ViewData["Clipfile"], archiveDate = ViewData["ClipArchive"] , station =  ViewData["ClipStation"] }) %>" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42e01e, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

The video that is not playable with the above code is shared here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1rjligqyjzfe4x/VOSOT_ASHLEY_FOODIE%20FRIDAY_FEDERAL%20DONUTS_CCAM.mp4?dl=0

This is mp4 file of size 17 MB and this problem is in chrome browser

Please help me what am I doing wrong here!

Edit1:

I got to know where I'm doing wrong. I updated the source tag to the following and it works now(Add @ before Url.Action)

```
 <source src="@Url.Action("Proxy", "Clip", new { file = ViewData["Clipfile"], archiveDate = ViewData["ClipArchive"] , station =  ViewData["ClipStation"] })" type='video/mp4'/>
```

Comment: seems to work fine in a quick test here, though I stripped out your poster and data-setup tags. Have you tried building up the `<video><source /></video>` tags bit by bit to see where it breaks? Does the video play if hard coded for you? Do you have any network or javascript errors (in browser tools)

Comment: This works fine when I hard code the video. But it doesn't work when I want the source to be a remote link(using Url.Action) for large size files

Comment: I got to know where I'm doing wrong. I changed the source tag to this and it works now. 
<source src="@Url.Action("Proxy", "Clip", new { file = ViewData["Clipfile"], archiveDate = ViewData["ClipArchive"] , station =  ViewData["ClipStation"] })" type='video/mp4'/>

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like your opening video tag is properly colored, which leads me to believe that you have a missing ">" or that somewhere above it in your  code you have something missing that is restricting the code from running properly in Google Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The same code displays and plays mp4 videos of size less than 10 MB. For size more than 10 MB, do I have to do anything different?

Comment: @Swathik, an additional recommendation would be to go through your code little by little and see where there is an issue. Also sometimes I have issues with opening and closing the same tag within itself, and so rather than <source /> I would try <source></source>. Sometimes that helps, sometimes it doesn't. From the little snippet of code that your provided it looks the the last </video> tag is not being linked with the opening properly. That can stem from another tag that is not properly closed, such as the source tag, which is why I would recommend trying to close it separately.